# perl's split function not working properly for UTF-16 encoding

Tags: perl, encoding, split, utf-16

Ques: Why this last line which doesn't have CFLF in the end not being properly split by perl's split function. It should show 5 fields.

input file has these lines. Last line doesnt have CRLF (carriage return and Line feed)

```
1;P7;extended ascii ÀÇÊ;;
2;P8;non-ascii ΩЖאഉて;;
3;P8;non-ascii ΩЖאഉて;;
```

my code is,

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Encode;
use utf8;
my $COL_SEP=';';
open FL, "<:encoding(UTF-16)", $ARGV[0] or die "canot open\n";
while(my $line= <FL>) {
chomp $line;
    print "$. length=",length($line),"\n";
#   print "\n",$line,"\n";
    my @fields = split($COL_SEP, $line);
    print "number of fields=",scalar(@fields),"\n";
}
close FL;
```

out put is

```
1 length=26
number of fields=5
2 length=23
number of fields=5
3 length=22
number of fields=3
```

Answer (score 4):

For the first line, `split` returns `"1", "P7", "extended ascii ÀÇÊ", "", "\r"`

For the second line, `split` returns `"2", "P8", "non-ascii ΩЖאഉて", "", "\r"`

For the third line, `split` would return `"3", "P8", "non-ascii ΩЖאഉて", "", ""` except that `split` drops empty trailing fields by default.

### Problem 1: Improper removal of line terminator.

Change

```
open(FL, "<:encoding(UTF-16)", $ARGV[0])
```

to

```
open(FL, "<:encoding(UTF-16):crlf", $ARGV[0])
```

If you want this to work properly on Windows too, that needs to be

```
open(FL, "<:raw:encoding(UTF-16):crlf", $ARGV[0])
```

Of course, you shouldn't be using global variables, so that should really be

```
open(my $FL, "<:raw:encoding(UTF-16):crlf", $ARGV[0])
```

### Problem 2: Preservation of empty trailing fields.

Change

```
my @fields = split($COL_SEP, $line);
```

to

```
my @fields = split($COL_SEP, $line, -1);
```

Of course, the first argument of `split` is expected to be a regex pattern, so that should really be

```
my @fields = split(quotemeta($COL_SEP), $line, -1);
```

or

```
my @fields = split(qr/\Q$COL_SEP/, $line, -1);
```

or

```
my @fields = split(/\Q$COL_SEP/, $line, -1);
```

Comment: great! that fixed my issue :)
Also I didn't know about 
1) split trims last field if it is empty. Link which educates this pls. 
2) all the components (first and third) of "<:raw:encoding(UTF-16):crlf". Although they are self explanatory, I would still like to read documentation on this. Any link appreciated.

Comment: Also is it best practice to use -1 with split?
my @fields = split($COL_SEP, $line, -1);

Comment: 1) [`split`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html). /// 2) `:raw` is basically binmode with no second arg. In this case, it prevents `:crlf` from being added before `:encoding` (something Perl does on Windows). You already know `:encoding`. `:crlf` cause CRLF=>LF on read and LF=>CRLF on write. /// 3) It all depends on what you want. Usually, I either want `-1` or it doesn't matter.